# Firebase stripe extension Error creating secrets

Tags: firebase, stripe-payments, firebase-extensions

I have my firebase stripe extension working properly in production this past few days. Yesterday, upon checking the app, it does not work anymore whenever i click subscribe. I check the firebase firestore and the necessary data are not being created. i check the firebase stripe extension configuration and it seems that the secret keys are misconfigured as im the only one working on this.

I tried copying the secret keys but every time i click 'create secret', it throw the error 'there was an error fetching your secrets'

i already tried uninstalling and reinstalling firebase stripe extension and this always appear and could not move forward

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OaIlP.png)

Answer (score 0):

After I researched a little.
I found that you can only use the same secret key that was generated when you installed the extension for the first time.
To solve it you can try to follow these steps:

- Use a new version of the same secret key that was previously used1. You can create a new version at the Google Secret Manager.
- Install a new instance of the extension with a different secret key2. You can install multiple instances of the extension per project.
- Uninstall the stripe/firestore-stripe-payments extension and install the [invertase/firestore-stripe-payments extension](https://github.com/invertase/stripe-firebase-extensions), which is a fork of the original extension with some bug fixes and improvements.